# Adding Days To Date in SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to get data from my Database of those who have upcoming birth days in next few days(declared earlier)
it's working fine for days but this query will not work if i add 24 days to current date cause than it will need change in month.
i wonder how can i do it

```
    declare @date int=10,
@month int=0
select * from STUDENT_INFO where DATEPART(DD,STDNT_DOB) between 
DATEPART(DD,GETDATE()) and  DATEPART(DD,DATEADD(DD,@date,GETDATE()))
and
DATEPART(MM,STDNT_DOB) = DATEPART(MM,DATEADD(MM,@month,GETDATE()))
```

This query works fine but it only checks date between 8 & 18

but if i use it like this

```
declare @date int=30,
@month int=0
select * from STUDENT_INFO where DATEPART(DD,STDNT_DOB) between 
DATEPART(DD,GETDATE()) and  DATEPART(DD,DATEADD(DD,@date,GETDATE()))
and
DATEPART(MM,STDNT_DOB) = DATEPART(MM,DATEADD(MM,@month,GETDATE()))
```

it will return nothing since it require addition in month as well

If I Use it like this

```
declare @date int=40,
@month int=0
select * from STUDENT_INFO where DATEPART(DD,STDNT_DOB) between 
DATEPART(DD,GETDATE()) and  DATEADD(DD,@date,GETDATE())
and
DATEPART(MM,STDNT_DOB) = DATEPART(MM,DATEADD(MM,@month,GETDATE()))
```

than it will return results till the last of this month but will not show till 18/12 which was required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple way to solve it:

```
DECLARE @date int = 10
;WITH cte as
(
SELECT cast(getdate() as date) fromdate, 
cast(getdate() as date) todate,
1 loop
UNION ALL
SELECT cast(dateadd(year, -loop, getdate()) as date), 
cast(dateadd(year, -loop, getdate())+@date as date),
loop+1
FROM cte
WHERE loop < 200 -- go back 200 years 
                 -- (should be enough unless you are a turtle)
)
SELECT dob, name, datediff(year, dob, getdate()) will_turn 
FROM cte
JOIN (values(cast('1968-11-11' as date), 'Jack'), 
            (cast('1984-11-12' as date), 'Jill'), 
            (cast('1984-11-13' as date), 'Hans'), 
            (cast('1984-11-21' as date), 'Gretchen'), 
            (cast('1884-11-22' as date), 'Snowwhite')) x(dob, name)
ON dob BETWEEN fromdate and todate
OPTION (maxrecursion 300)
```

Returns:

```
dob name    name     will_turn
1984-11-12  Jill     29
1984-11-13  Hans     29
1984-11-21  Gretchen 29
1968-11-11  Jack     45
```

Comment: let me apply this in my scene

Comment: How does your answer relate to the OP's question? Sorry but I fail to see the relationship.

Comment: Oh, now I see it, but it wasn't readily clear from your answer. You have a function that gives the age at a given date, then you calculate the students age today and compares it to their age at @date days in the future. Whoever has a greater age in the near future has an upcoming birthday. Gotcha!

Answer (score 0):

Would this work for you?

```
declare @date int = 10
select * from STUDENT_INFO 
where DATEDIFF(DD, GETDATE(), 
               DATEFROMPARTS(DATEPART(YYYY, GETDATE()), -- this years birthday
                             DATEPART(MM, STDNT_DOB), 
                             DATEPART(DD, STDNT_DOB))) between 0 and @date
   or DATEDIFF(DD, GETDATE(), 
               DATEFROMPARTS(DATEPART(YYYY, GETDATE()) + 1, -- next years birthday
                             DATEPART(MM, STDNT_DOB), 
                             DATEPART(DD, STDNT_DOB))) between 0 and @date
```

The trick here is to get the students birthday this year (and next year) and get the number of days until that date. I did that by creating a calculated field using the students day and month of birth, and included todays year.

The check against next years birthday (i.e., the second part of the OR clause) is required to get those students whose upcoming birthday is early next year.

**Edit:** the query will **fail** if anyone on the table was born on feb/29 (on a leap year, of course). Thanks to t-clausen.dk for poiting it out.

Comment: @t-clausen.dk What exactly is wrong with my query? Would you care to edit my answer to correct it?

Comment: @t-clausen.dk Yes, DATEFROMPARTS is only available in SQL Server 2012. But one could create the dates as a concatenation of their parts as char type. It's just more verbose, but it would work.

Comment: your script has an issue when people are born on february 29. Making DateFromParts a pretty useless function(go fix microsoft). Furthermore you added +1 to fix next years birthday the wrong place

Comment: @t-clausen.dk Right. Now you've been helpful. Thanks! I've edited the query to fix the +1 for next years date, but I don't feel like there's any elegant fix for the birthdays in feb/29. I have a cousin who was born on feb/29, but his folks just moved his birthday to march, 1st, to avoid problems. That's a better fix ;)

Answer (score 0):

avoiding udf:-

```
create table #dob (
    name varchar(50),
    cakeday date
)
go
insert into #dob values
    ('yesterday',dateadd(yy,-50,getdate()-1)),
    ('today',dateadd(yy,-51,getdate())),
    ('ten days',dateadd(yy,-52,getdate()+10)),
    ('eleven days',dateadd(yy,-53,getdate()+11))
go
select *
from #dob d
where datepart(dayofyear,d.cakeday) 
    between datepart(dayofyear,getdate()) and datepart(dayofyear,getdate())+10
```

returns (on 2013-11-09):-

```
name        cakeday
today       1962-11-09
ten days    1961-11-19
```

Comment: probably out by a day or so on leap years...  but may be close enough