# Findout if a user is older than 18 T-SQL

Tags: t-sql

I have a table that contains a birthday in the format (YYYYMMDD) eg '19951118'

What is the most efficient way to findout if the user has turned 18?

I add my solution in the post instead of a comment:
SELECT * from Users where DATEADD(YEAR,18,BirthDay) > DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, getdate()), 0)

Comment: I solved it like this SELECT * from Users where DATEADD(YEAR,18,BirthDay) > DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, getdate()), 0)

Comment: If you care about efficiency why are you storing dates as strings? `date` is 3 bytes compared with 8 bytes for `char(8)`. Plus if you use the correct datatype you don't need to cast or run the risk of nonsense dates.

Comment: @MartinSmith: I assume that he's just confusing the output of his `datetime` column with a _format_.

Comment: @TimSchmelter - Dunno what you base that assumption on. `YYYYMMDD` is not how datetimes are displayed by default and there seems to be a never ending supply of questions asked by people not using correct date/time datatypes.

Comment: @MartinSmith: `declare @BirthDate datetime = '19951118'`

Comment: @user2916136 - I just noticed your comment immediately under the question. `where DATEADD(YEAR,18,BirthDay) >` is not efficient. That isn't sargable. Use the correct datatype for the column and `WHERE BirthDay <= DATEADD(YEAR,-18,GETDATE())`

Comment: Learn how to calculate age [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19853970/adding-days-to-date-in-sql/19856002#19856002) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18588672/count-the-amount-of-years-from-a-certain-date-sql/18593995#18593995)

Comment: Well the problem is that i cant change how the data is stored in the Table and it is stored on the format and the reason i asked how to get better performance is mainly to speed thins up as much as possible without changing how the data is stored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your dateofbirth is char(8), this will perform well on a large table because there is no calculation on the column birthday.

```
WHERE 
 REPLACE(CONVERT(CHAR(10), DATEADD(YEAR,-18,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP), 126), '-', '') 
 >= birthday
```

Answer (score 2):

If you store date of birth as a varchar then

```
WHERE DateDiff(month,CONVERT(datetime,'19951118',112),getdate())>=18*12
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/25290)

Comment: This would not perform well and it returns the wrong result, check @MartinSmith's - and my comments